# Office Word Table fill page bounds

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, syncfusion

i'm developing an invoice template using Syncfusion DocIo with merge fields.
Everything works fine but i have a problem, I use a repeater for rows and every time happen that table ends at half of the page and it's not nice to see.I need that the invoice must stay at full page, fitted to the page bounds, I need something like a "dynamic spacer".

You have any suggest to keep the table stretched at bounds?

Many thanks for help

Comment: You don't provide enough information about how the result should look. It's not clear *exactly* what you want.

Comment: We have prepared a simple mail merge application (given in the below link) which increases the table row height while performing mail merge operation. Please a have a look into it. http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/GenerateWord-1608535274.zip If it doesn't meet your requirement, please create a support ticket in Syncfusion support system with your input template document and excepted output document. https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac Regards,
Sarath